# How to replace before and after characters of a particular string

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linux, shell

I am working on converting SQL server inserts into MySQL inserts using some Linux file level operations.
Can some one please let me know how to convert all occurrences of below in a line

```
(..,CAST(0x0000722300000000 AS DateTime),..,CAST(0x0000979900C10112 AS DateTime),...)
```

as shown below

```
(..,myfunc(0x0000722300000000),..,myfunc(0x0000979900C10112),...)
```

EXAMPLE:

Need to convert CAST(hexval AS DateTime) as myfunc(hexval) where hexval is dynamic.

```
$echo "(..,CAST(0x0000722300000000 AS DateTime),..,CAST(0x0000979900C10112 AS DateTime),...)" | using grep or sed or awk 

(..,myfunc(0x0000722300000000),..,myfunc(0x0000979900C10112),...)
```

Comment: @vidhyadar can you please eloberate your question more understandable way ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this sed one-liner will help:

```
sed 's/CAST(\([^)]\+\) AS DateTime)/myfunc(\1)/g' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
(..,CAST(0x0000722300000000 AS DateTime),..,CAST(0x0000979900C10112 AS DateTime),...)

kent$  sed 's/CAST(\([^)]\+\) AS DateTime)/myfunc(\1)/g' f
(..,myfunc(0x0000722300000000),..,myfunc(0x0000979900C10112),...)
```

Comment: @vidyadhar `s/...foo.../bar/g` will replace all `...foo...` with `bar`. the rest  stuff is regex. which part you don't understand?

Comment: @kent I didn't understand \([^)]\+\) and \1 which are used inside command..can you explain what they are doing

Comment: @vidyadhar `[^)]\+` is one or more non- `)` characters. `\1` references the regex group, which is the match between the first pair of `(...)`